# How to test if a reflected field's type is, or inherits from, a specified type

Tags: c#, reflection

I am iterating through the `FieldInfo` of a class.  I want to be able to test if a given field is of a certain type.

The specific issue is that I want to know all fields that are derived from `SortedList`.  So they are not exactly `SortedList`, but each one IS a `SortedList`.
Given the field's `FieldInfo`, how do I test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking for the SortedList as the type, you can also look for interfaces such as  IDictionary, ICollection which [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) derives from. I provide an interesting read on my blog which gives an example of reflecting for an interface:

[Reflect Interface from Unknown Assembly in C#](http://omegacoder.com/?p=65)

HTH (From HR down south of you ;-) )

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to perform this test, like this:

```
var isSortedList = typeof(SortedList).IsAssignableFrom(fieldInfo.FieldType);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool canCast = (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(SortedList) ||
               (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SortedList)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(SortedList)) || fieldInfo.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SortedList))
    Console.WriteLine("Field {0} is of type {1}", fieldInfo.Name, typeof(blah.Name));
```

This code is untested but is roughly what I have used before.